# Apache .htaccess RewriteRule not including subdirectory when redirecting non-www to www url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've setup a rewrite rule in order to direct `domain.com` traffic to `www.domain.com` using the following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

From my limited understanding, the `$1` in the `RewriteRule` should match anything after `domain.com/` and then be placed at the end of my rewritten url `www.domain.com/`.

For example `domain.com/abc` should become `www.domain.com/abc`.

However this is **not working**. If I browse to `domain.com/abc` then this path isn't rewritten at all and I just get `domain.com/abc` without the `www`.

I've done lots of reading just to figure out that the `$1` should be taking care of this, from my understanding.

Can anyone explain why it isn't working as I suspect it should be? Thanks.

Comment: That means this rule isn't executing at all. Comment out both `IfModule` lines and retest.

Comment: It will also depend on the context where you specified that. If your request is not hitting the specific virtualhost where you specified it it won't affect it either, etc. It is a very complicated way of doing things however, specifying the correct `ServerName` in the virtualhost and setting the directive `UseCanonicalName on`in the virtualhost should have been enough.

Comment: This is working, except for the `$1`. As in, before I set this rule I don't get redirected from `domain.com` and once I set this rule I get redirected to `www.domain.com`. However subdirectories do not work, which is where the confusion arises.

Comment: which means that rewrite is not being used, instead some other is.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more explicit. My knowledge of RewriteRules and Apache is very limited. This is the only RewriteRule I have setup. If I remove this code, no redirection happens.

Comment: I'm using Wordpress. Could W3 Cache be messing with this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because I was using Wordpress AND W3 Cache plugin that I was simply putting the code in the wrong place in my .htaccess file.

The code should be placed within the `# BEGIN Wordpress` codeblock and before the existing rules that Wordpress already has in place.

The existing code should look something like this:

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END Wordpress
```

I added my original code to this as follows:

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END Wordpress
```

This fixes the issue I was describing above. Thanks to the commenters for sparking my thought process.